# UIView with auto layout constraints "jumps" before transform animation

Tags: ios, autolayout, ios-animations

I have a UIView constrained with Auto Layout. It's centered and has a constraint for Width and Height. When it appears, I'm applying a rotation transform to it.

[image: Rotated View]

When I hit that animation button, I want it to animate to a point higher on the screen, while rotating back to an "upright" position (ie with no rotation applied). So, I set a new translation transform:

```
let translation = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 1, y: -100)
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
   self.blueView.transform = translation
})
```

What I expect to see is the view rotate back to an upright position while translating upwards.

What I get instead is the view "jumping" to a point off to the right, and then animating upwards while rotating.

How can I fix this so that it doesn't "jump" before animating?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing the jump because the `blueView` already has the rotation transform set when you animate the translation transform. That leads to unexpected results.

To make it work you combine the rotation and translation transform **before** the animation and then reset the transform animated:

To translate the blue view **100pt up** and rotate it back to normal you do this:

1. Add a transform to the `blueView` that translates it **100pt down** and rotates it 45°
2. Set the centerYAnchor constant to **-100** to have the blueView in the correct position before the animation.
3. Animate the `blueView.transform = .identity` to remove the transform animated

This is a working example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let blueView = UIView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        blueView.backgroundColor = .blue
        view.addSubview(blueView)

        blueView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 100).rotated(by: -CGFloat.pi / 4)

        let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
        button.setTitle("Animate", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(.blue, for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didPress), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(button)

        blueView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            blueView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20),
            blueView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20),
            blueView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            blueView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: -100),

            button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            button.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -40)
            ])
    }

    @objc func didPress(sender: UIButton) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
            self.blueView.transform = .identity
        })
    }
}
```